# Intellij Error: Environment variable name is not set

Tags: intellij-idea

At the bottom of run configuration there is the error message :
Error: Environment variable name is not set

When I click on the "Fix" button,  an empty line is created in the "environment variables" section in the startup/connection tab.
What variable is missing ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the "-" button at the bottom, it looks like there is some empty environment variable set or your existing variables were not parsed correctly which has added a blank variable.

If you have the steps to reproduce it with the broken environment variable that cannot be parsed, please [report a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA).